# Why are vectors significantly slower than arrays in this implementation of a sorting algorithm?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, benchmarking

An implementation of a MergeSort was using `vector`s to copy data from the argument `toBeSorted`. By changing it, so that a regular array is allocated and each value copied "by hand", the program is executed way faster (details at the bottom).

I expected some overhead, but the scale of a difference surprised me. I thought that constructing a vector would be hardly any slower than allocating an array with `new`.

The code (I removed the actual merging to minimize the example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define USE_VECTORS

void Merge(vector<int>& toBeSorted, int left, int middle, int right) {
  int rightPartSize = (-1) * (middle - right);
  int leftPartSize = (middle - left) + 1;

#ifdef USE_VECTORS

  vector<int> leftPart{toBeSorted.begin() + left,
                            toBeSorted.begin() + left + leftPartSize};

  vector<int> rightPart{toBeSorted.begin() + middle + 1,
                            toBeSorted.end()};
#else

  int* leftPart = new int[leftPartSize];
  for (int i = 0; i < leftPartSize; i++) {
    leftPart[i] = (toBeSorted[left + i]);
  }

  int* rightPart = new int[rightPartSize];
  for (int i = 0; i < rightPartSize; i++) {
    rightPart[i] = (toBeSorted[middle + i + 1]);
  }

  delete[] leftPart;
  delete[] rightPart;
#endif
}

void MergeSort(vector<int>& toBeSorted, int left, int right) {
  if (left < right) {
    int middle = (left + right) / 2;
    MergeSort(toBeSorted, left, middle);
    MergeSort(toBeSorted, middle + 1, right);
    Merge(toBeSorted, left, middle, right);
  }
}

int main() {

  const int SIZE = 100000;
  std::vector<int> x(SIZE, 0);

  clock_t t_start = clock();
  MergeSort(x, 0, int(x.size()) - 1);
  clock_t t_end = clock();

  double elapsedTime = (t_end - t_start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  cout << "Time: " << elapsedTime << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Run it on [rextester](https://rextester.com/QSSJN90117), the time I'm getting is around 1.2 second.
Uncomment the `#define USE_VECTORS` to see the time for the arrays version. For that, I'm seeing ~0.009 second.

Comment: Is this an optimized / Release build?

Comment: You probably should use `std::chrono` instead of clock. [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/)

Comment: My guess is that since you don't do anything with the arrays, the compiler just optimizes the whole thing away.  With vector that's harder to do, so it doesn't.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was seeing similar results for the fully implemented MergeSort.

Comment: I'm guessing @NathanOliver is right.  There's no actual sorting occurring here, and everything might change if that were fixed.

Comment: Unless you use the result the compiler can throw away the entire sorting because it knows the program does not need the result of the sort

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think anything is optimized out. See on godbolt, that everything seems to be there: https://godbolt.org/z/xg_e7f

Comment: Do you use compiler optimization? In the godbolt link optimization is disabled.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Passing -O0 to rextester raises the execution time for the arrays to 0.016 of a second. It's still a big difference.

Comment: Clang, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TrvDaK), is more aggressive.

Comment: You have issue with the second vector - `rightPart`, if you comment it out problem disappears. Looks like you just doing different job on 2 different branches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code that calculates `rightPartSize` is not consistent with how you create `rightPart` vector. You can easily check it by adding this statement:

```
if( static_cast<size_t>( rightPartSize ) != rightPart.size() ) 
      cout << rightPartSize << " != " << rightPart.size() << endl;
```

after `rightPart` creation:

```
1 != 99999
1 != 99997
2 != 99998
1 != 99995
1 != 99994
3 != 99996
1 != 99992
1 != 99991
1 != 99989
1 != 99988
3 != 99990
6 != 99993
1 != 99986
1 != 99985
1 != 99983
...
```

so amount of work done by vector is significantly bigger than what you do with your dynamic array.

Comment: I was trying to wrap my head around how the calculation / size is different but I see now `toBeSorted` is the entire vector. So you have middle+1 to the end of the entire vector not just to toBeSorted[right].

Comment: As usual, PEBCAK.

Just to confirm, when I fix the rightPartVector like this:

`vector<int> rightPart{toBeSorted.begin() + middle + 1, toBeSorted.begin() + middle + 1 + rightPartSize};`

the times are finally similar.